# Buying a Towel Based on Maximum Hypothenuse Length

Tags: geometry

I'm planning to buy a rectangle shaped towel. I have measured the maximum height between the loop and the surface below the hook where I plan to hang the towel. My plan is to look at each towel in the store and draw an imaginary perpendicular line from the loop to the other side of the towel and then compare the hypothenuse of the bigger rectangle with my measurement. The loops are typically attached at either the middle of a side or in the corner which makes calculating the length of the sides easy from the numbers available in the price tags. However, the ratio between the sides of the towel have some variation. Some of the towels are squares but there seems to be lots of different ratios. This creates the problem that I have to separately calculate the hypothenuse of each towel in the store before I can compare them with my measurement. I'm looking for a general rule that would let me quickly determine which towels in the store are small enough to not touch the surface below the hook without having to individually calculate the hypothenuse of each towel.

Comment: just use the calculator on your phone. or buy only towels with the loop in the middle.

Comment: Using a calculator is a hassle. Loop in the middle doesn't solve the problem. I guess a stick representing the correct length would be an efficient outside the box solution.

Comment: @trula Excellent...

Comment: Buy one of each towel, and return the ones that don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

One simplification that you can do is avoid the square root and instead compare the square of the hypothenuse. You can use the square of the available distance in your bathroom in mind for reference. Then you can compute $a^2+b^2$ for each candidate and compare it against that.

This still entails mentally taking two squares and adding them, and there is no simple way around that unless you want to start using approximations, heuristics, precomputed tables, or a pocket calculator.